# Azure functions: Read config from host.json after deploy

Tags: c#, json, configuration, azure-functions

I've made an azure function in C#.
I use local.settings.json for testing locally. Everything works correctly with

```
ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["key"]
```

Now I have published it. Nothing is working anymore. Host.json is there, I can browse the function app settings tab and I can see the configuration host.json right there with all the values.

Host.json format is the same as local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "MYCONFIG": "HEY",
    "THEOTHERCONFIG" : "WHASSUP"
  }
}
```

If I run locally everything is working fine.
If I publish I get null in all the values.

I tried

```
    ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["key"]
```

and

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYCONFIG", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Nothing works.

Microsoft documentation doesn't unveil the sacred secret of reading a config file.

[Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1594) I see they don't even mention a host.json file, they just say you have to manually put them in the azure portal.... which is higly impractical.

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: you need to put your config in the appsettings blade of the azure functions (portal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings in the **local.settings.json** file are **only used by Functions tools when running locally**. By default, these settings are **not migrated** automatically when the project is published to Azure.
 We could use the [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-functions-core-tools) to publish the local.setting.json to Azure easily.

```
func azure functionapp publish azurefunctionname --publish-local-settings
```

> The **[host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json)** metadata file contains global configuration options that affect all functions for a function app.

host.json is not for config Azure function appsettings.

**Or** as Thomas mentioned that you could config it in your appsettings blade of the azure function.

[image]

**Update:**

> If you want to delegate some developement and testing you have to give them credentials... how ridiculous

You could use the [Key vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) and [Azure function MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity) to avoid sharing your credentials.

Comment: Well, it seems the only way. No config file, everything online. If you want to delegate some developement and testing you have to give them credentials... how ridiculous

Comment: `If you want to delegate some developement and testing you have to give them credentials... how ridiculous`. You could config credentials in the azure function appsetting on the azure portal to avoid sharing your credentials to other people.  Or you could use keyvault and  [Azure function MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity) to avoid sharing your credentials.

Comment: @TomSun Is it possible to put my custom settings in host.json file and use that?

Comment: Thanks Tom. Your comment `host.json is not for config Azure function appsettings.` is the only reference I could find that states your app should not use this for general configuration options, and use the App settings in the Azure blade instead.

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate that `host.json` might not be there for configuring `appsettings`, but just as an answer to the question...

As read in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#override-hostjson-values):

*When the runtime finds an application setting in the format AzureFunctionsJobHost__path__to__setting, it overrides the equivalent host.json setting*

Example. You'd override the below `host.json` file:

```
{
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
              "isEnabled": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With `appsettings.json`/`local.settings.json`:

```
{
...
    "Values": {
"AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__applicationInsights__samplingSettings__isEnabled":"false"
...
    }
}
```

This means you can dynamically control what's in host.json this way. Not quite an answer to the OPs question, since it's not accessing but overriding, but I think it's a somewhat valid way to control what's in `host.json`. If it's a good practice, or not - not me to decide :-)

Comment: I wasn't able to override a host setting in the `appsettings.json` file, but `local.settings.json` worked fine. Using Azure Functions v4.